# Return fields from query used for INSERT values

Tags: postgresql

When using a `SELECT` query to produce values for an `INSERT` like this:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (
  foo,
  bar
)
SELECT
  at.foo,
  at.bar
FROM another_table at;
```

How to return the fields from the `SELECT` query in the `RETURNING` clause along with the newly INSERTED rows? Something like:

```
INSERT INTO some_table AS t (
  foo,
  bar
)
SELECT
  at.foo,
  at.bar
FROM another_table at
RETURNING t.id, at.id;
```

I'm sure I've done this before or I've overlooked something really obvious.

Is it possible to do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=aecde106ec1ed797ca26e778f0dc29c3)

```
WITH selecting AS (
    SELECT id, x FROM a 
), inserting AS (
    INSERT INTO b AS b (y) 
    SELECT x FROM selecting
    RETURNING id, y
)
SELECT
    i.id, 
    s.id
FROM 
    inserting i
JOIN
    selecting s
ON i.y = s.x
```

You can try a CTE approach. First selecting all relevant data, store the result internally. After that do the `INSERT` statement with these data, store the `RETURNING` values internally. After all you can you all saved data, combine them with a join and print out what you want.

Comment: Is order guaranteed when querying a CTE? I just realized I was thinking of UPDATE. You can return fields from the from clauses with RETURNING when using UPDATE

Comment: The CTE is the same as a simple subquery. It only stores the data internally for further usage. If you want to ensure a certain order you have to put it into both the subquery as well as the CTE. There is no problem with that :)

Comment: your solution did not really answer the question, which was can the fields of the query providing the values for the insert be returned? The answer is no.  While your solution is good for some scenarios, it does not fit here.  Also your solution assumes the two id fields are equal, which most likely they are not.  You've also used an unqualified `JOIN` which is really a `CROSS JOIN`, and nobody wants that. :).  I've answered this question myself.

Comment: I am not quiet sure if I understand your problem: First, there is no cross join but a qualified inner join. A cross join would result in this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f15b616347070b94b3890b5ef5fb49cd Second: The query gives you exactly these records that have been inserted and combine them (with the join) with the right returning id without re-executing the queries. Isn't it this what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to return the fields from the query that provides the values for an `INSERT`.  You can only return fields from the newly inserted rows.

An `UPDATE` can return fields from the updated rows as well as from the **from list** of the query.